# Why does apache software foundation disllow inclusion of LGPL libraries in its projects but allows other "weak copyleft" lecenses?

Tags: lgpl, copyleft

I just noticed an ASF contributor mentioning this on issue tracker of a library that ASF disallows downstream LGPL dependencies. I traced down ASF's policy to this page: https://www.apache.org/legal/resolved.html . It mentions LGPL under [Category X: What can we NOT include in an ASF Project? > Places restrictions on larger works:](https://www.apache.org/legal/resolved.html#category-x)

If my understanding of LGPL is correct, then you can use LGPL dependency as a library in a project that has any other license (even a proprietary license), and you incur no additional obligations unless you're making modifications to the library itself. This is understanding is also echoed [here on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Lesser_General_Public_License#Differences_from_the_GPL). Is my understanding correct?

If so, I don't understand why someone would not want to include a LGPL library. I ask this from the point of view of say someone who's developing libraries to release under LGPL.

Moreover it seems that ASF allows several "weak copyleft" licenses https://www.apache.org/legal/resolved.html#weak-copyleft-licenses, which may help in answering my question by narrowing it down to "what do the allowed set of licenses have that LGPL doesn't have?", but I haven't been able to answer that myself either.

Comment: Quoting from the very Wikipedia page you link to: "if it is a "work that uses the library", then it must be possible for the software to be linked with a newer version of the LGPL-covered program". That is precisely what the Apache folks want to avoid under "places restrictions on larger works".

Comment: Ah that's subtle but I didn't quite realize that that'd be a problem. Reading through https://www.gnu.org/licenses/lgpl-3.0.html#section4 , it seems that one additional restriction is allowing user of the software to be able to swap out the included version of the library for a library of their choice, is that also right?

Comment: Btw if you post your comment as an answer, I could accept it, since it has answered the question I had